# How to reveal the control center in ios using appium?

Tags: java, ios, appium, appium-ios

I am not able to swipe from bottom to top in ios. I was able to this with an older version of appium (any version before 1.5.0)
Now I am working with Appium v.1.6.0 -beta1 because I want to work with xcode 8 and ios 10. Since I am working with v.1.6.0 -beta, I am not able to perform a swipe from bottom of the screen to top in order to reveal the control center and click on the wifi button.
Is this a bug or there is something I should perform?
Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ? I'm using 1.6.0 beta as well. Thanks

Comment: not yet. i will post the solution if i find any.